# xunit assert.equal bug?

Tags: .net, xunit

I just started working on a new project with a ton of existing code, and the tests are not passing. I'm more of an Nunit guy, so I'm not immediately familiar with the failure points of Xunit.

the problem is in code that sort of looks like this:

```
fooStringProperty = readSomeFile;
//later
fooStringProperty.ShouldBe(expectedContents)
```

the above code fails with an error that looks like this:

```
error : Position: First difference is at position 0
Expected: contentsOfFooStringProperty      
Actual:
contentsOfFooStringProperty
```

basically, it's somehow getting this newline in there, and I have no idea how. I have a ton of these failures all over the code base, and it works for other people, so I'm wondering if it's some xunit version issue?

edit: this is totally a CRLF issue between mac and windows. problem resolved :)

Comment: More likely you have a bug in your code. Time to get out the ol' debugger and see what's going on. It's very unlikely xUnit is to blame here.

Comment: are you running into platform differences? (\r\n vs. \n line-ends?) What runtime version/OS is this?

Comment: **[Select Isn't Broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)** (especially true when your user name is close to being an anagram of **[Occam Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor)**, Oren Mazor :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely that xUnit is injecting newlines. It seems more likely that you really *have* got rogue newlines, for some completely other reason.

I would suggest that you diagnose this by debugging through the code and checking the values in the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the assertion line, and see whether it looks right to you. Assuming it really *is* broken at that point, put a breakpoint where you're fetching/reading/computing each value. Basically apply the normal steps to working out unexpected behaviour - ignore the xUnit aspect.

Comment: that'd be my normal assumption as well, except this code works perfectly fine for the rest of the time. only broken on my machine… clean new machine.

Comment: @OrenMazor: That doesn't make it xUnit's fault :) Are you able to debug the unit tests? If not, you'll need to resort to debug-via-logging, which is slightly more painful. I'm sure it'll turn out to be something environmental.

Comment: I completely agree. it's almost guaranteed to be 100% environmental. I just wanted to ask on here in parallel with my debugging, since I dont know much of xunit and wanted a second opinion.